# How to save encoded CMSampleBuffer samples to mp4 file on iOS

Tags: ios, swift, avcapturesession, cmsamplebuffer, video-toolbox

I'm using the VideoToolbox framework to retrieve data from AVCaptureSession and encode it to h264 and acc.

I'm at a point where I:

1. obtain data using the delegate method `func captureOutput(_ captureOutput: AVCaptureOutput, didOutput sampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer, from connection: AVCaptureConnection)`
2. convert video `CMSampleBuffer` to `CVImageBuffer` and encode it to h264 using `VTCompressionSession` which passes the encoded frame in `VTCompressionOutputCallback`
3. encode audio `CMSampleBuffer` to acc and pass it as `UnsafeMutableAudioBufferListPointer`.

I'm now blocked at a point where I want to correctly convert these streams to bytes of `Data` to write to a url through `FileHandle`. How should I go about this?

I need to have access to encoded streams **before** the actual file is finalized so I can't use (I think) `AVAssetWriter` to save unencoded streams to an mp4 file because from what I can tell I need to pass unencoded samples to `AVAssetWriter` for it to work properly. Or am I mistaken?

Answer (score 1):

Turns out you can save encoded `CMSampleBuffer` using `AVAssetWriter` but you need to pass `nil` as outputSettings in `AVAssetWriterInput` to prevent re-encoding data:

```
let input AVAssetWriterInput(mediaType: mediaType, outputSettings: nil, sourceFormatHint: sourceFormatHint)
```